# How to Handle JSON data in android

Tags: android, json

Hey I have a project where by I have to parse a JSON object Its really giving me a hard time Handling this data to a format i can be able to use The Json data itself looks like this

```
{
"users": {
    "token": "FFFFFFFFF###5",
    "username": "wanjiku",
    "full name": "Wanjiku Karimi",
    "profilePic": "http://freevar.com/vr-content/uploads/2012/08/Freevar-Profile-Pictures-Pimp.jpg",
    "cradle": [
        {
            "name": "wanjiku's rock",
            "id": "1",
            "logo": "http://freevar.it/150x150"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

my code for retrieving this data from the JsonObject is like so

```
try{
    JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray jArray = null;

    jArray = json_data.getJSONArray("users");

    for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject c = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.println(c.getString("token"));

    }
```

please help me retrieve the data currently the error I'm getting is

org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one

```
JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray jArray = null;
  JSONObject   jobj = json_data.getJSONObject("users");
   System.out.println(jobj.getString("token"));
    System.out.println(jobj.getString("username"));
    System.out.println(jobj.getString("full name"));

     jArray = jobj .getJSONArray("cradle");
    for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject c = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.println(c.getString("name"));
       System.out.println(c.getString("id"));
        System.out.println(c.getString("logo"));

    }
```

[ -> this represent ths Json Array

{ -> this represent the Json Object

Answer (score 4):

users is not a JSONArray but a JSONObject:

Change

```
 jArray = json_data.getJSONArray("users");
```

with

```
 JSONObject jObj = json_data.getJSONObject("users");
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again your solution helped me access all the values until you get to cradle how do I access the other values in cradle

Comment: @user1534409 you can get the all data from json so refer my answer. it will help you